# Chess movies in Hollywood & Bollywood with GMs in them

Tags: grandmaster, world-championship, famous-players, film

Are there any movies about chess in which World Champions or grandmasters have played actually any role? For example, have Kasparov, Karpov, Anand, Carlsen, Kramnik, Polgar, Fischer, Tal or etc acted in the movie?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Grossmeyster](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0382724/). Mikhail Tal exchanges a few words with the main character. Keres, Kotov, Taymanov, Averbakh have cameo appearances. Victor Korchnoj plays the main character's coach.

I don't know if the English version exists.

Answer (score 1):

The 1993 American drama film [“Searching For Bobby Fischer”](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Searching_for_Bobby_Fischer), based on the book with the same, has a few cameos by grandmasters. Here is a list of them per Wikipedia.

1. [Anjelina Belakovskaia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anjelina_Belakovskaia), who has the title of Woman Grandmaster and has been the U.S. women's champion three times.
2. [Joel Benjamin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Benjamin) ,  an American grandmaster.
3. [Roman Dzindzichashvili](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Dzindzichashvili), an American grandmaster born in the USSR.

Comment: Thanks Rewan for the information provided. Do you feel Chess movies should be made with Current & Former World Chess champions playing active roles?

Comment: Thank you. The news press can ask them while taking their interviews whether they are interested to play any active roles in chess movies.